# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when receiving JSON data from server

Tags: javascript, java, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make the client side receiving JSON data from the Server, however, it constantly popped up the error method. When I try to use Chrome to debug, it popped up: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/TransportationNetwork/rest/paths?st=3,6. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have tried to change dataType to 'jsonp', but it doesn't work. However, when I use POSTMAN to test the data from Server, everything works fine, I can see the JSON data comes from the server.

**Here is the picture shows the testing result from POSTMAN:** 
[Pictures shows POSTMAN testing result from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zja3a.png)

**The following is my code on both server side and client side:**
 Could anyone tell me how to add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for my java code?(if it is this problem)

**The Java Code:**

```
@Path("/paths")
public class PathsResource {
    PathDao pathDao;

public PathsResource() {
    pathDao = new PathDao();
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
//@Consumes("text/plain")
public List<DirectedEdge> pathsInfo(@QueryParam("st") String st) {
    System.out.println("Searching paths : " + st);
    return pathDao.getEdgeList(st);
}  
}
```

**The Javascript:**

```
var serviceURL = "http://localhost:8080/TransportationNetwork/rest/paths";


$('#findPaths').click(function() {
        getPaths();
});

function getPaths() {
    console.log('display paths');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: serviceURL,
        dataType:'json', // data type get back from server
        data:'st=' + dataToServer(), //data sent to server 
        success: renderList,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Path Finder: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}

function dataToServer() {
    var array = "";
        str1 = $('#source').val();
        str2 = $('#target').val();

    array = str1 + "," + str2;

    return array;
}

function renderList(data) {
    //var parsedData = JSON.parse(data); 
    var list = data == null ? [] : (data instanceof Array ? data : [data]);
    $('#PathList li').remove();
    $.each(list, function(index, path) {
        $('#PathList').append('<li>'+ path.source + ' -> ' + path.target + ': ' + path.weight + '</li>');
    });
}
```

Comment: Please refer the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389031/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-rest-service-ajax

Comment: thank you, but I still don't understand it, it is in a different case. if I use that one, I need to change my code completely. that would be time consuming. @anaspa

Comment: what's the url of the  page which you met with errors

Comment: there only one url :http://localhost:8080/TransportationNetwork/rest/paths on the server side ,and when client side use GET method it send http://localhost:8080/TransportationNetwork/rest/paths?st=3,6 back to the server.  "st" is a variable to send a string "m,n" as can be seen in the code. @Marks

Comment: @user3765602 sorry i meant the web page url,not the web service you're requesting

Comment: Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. null is really wired

Comment: I don't have a web page url. it is just a localhost webservice @Marks